# Converting date column from factor into posixct makes my dataframe have a length and size of zero

Tags: r, dataframe, posixct

I am trying to figure out a problem I'm having with converting a `date` column from factor to posixct. I have a script which I have run several times with no issue. When I read my .csv file, it has a date column which comes as a factor. But I convert it into POSIXct using `as.POSIXct()` so I can create a plot and do some calculations.

Recently, I had to reinstall R. Now when I try to convert from factor to posixct, my dataframe length and size become zero. I have searched for a solution, but could not find a solution. Why would `as.POSIXct()` erase my dataframe?

```
   date     Julian   Hour   MINUTE   date1              v1

2004-04-25   116     18      0     2004-04-25 18:00      0.0000001

2004-04-25   116     18     30     2004-04-25 18:30      0.0000001

2004-04-25   116     19      0     2004-04-25 19:00      0.0000002

2004-04-25   116     19     30     2004-04-25 19:30      0.0000003

2004-04-25   116     21      0     2004-04-25 21:00      0.0000001
```

Comment: Try `read_csv()` instead of `read.csv()`. This will read in your strings as character variables rather than factors.

Comment: @MathNewbie can you share a sample of your data please? Even a 4x4 df would be great.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What error did you get?

Comment: I am trying to do read_csv(), it did not work, i dont know if my version works with read_csv.

Comment: paste a sample of your data from your R console. You can do something like head(dt) in the console and simply copy and paste it into code block in your original question!

Comment: @JamesMartherus i did not get any error. Only thing, in the environment window of Rstudio, it is not longer showing as a data.frame. As i will have to do some major calculation, i wonder if this might cause a problem afterwards.

Comment: Impossible to answer unless you post your code.

Comment: @BillO'Brien well, this is the code i used, which works perfectly before.
metHre <- read.csv(file="metHre_vpd.csv",sep=",")
date_info <- with(metHre,paste(yr,mon,day,Hr,Minute))
metHre$date1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(date_info,"%Y %m %d %H %M"))   
The problem is not with the code, i think its the ggplot version i am using or the posixct, as when i use the posixlt, the dataframe remains as a dataframe.

Comment: @JamesMartherus thank you so much. I checked online, and i found that read_csv need the tidyverse library, which i load, then the read_csv() command works. I used the read_csv2() command as my data had semi-colon instead of comma and it imports the file perfectly, with the date column as Date format and my datetime column as posixct. And the dataframe remains as a dataframe in the environment window of my Rstudio. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JamesMartherus I have another issue now. The read_csv2 reads my other numeric column as character. Its like a limitation using read_csv2 instead of read.csv.

Comment: Post this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to include stringsAsFactors = F in the read.csv() so that read.csv will read your strings as character instead of factors.